# Unable to get the children() after compilation within directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which compiles a template with radio buttons.
I'm trying to get the children after compilation and it doesn't show up.
Where am I going wrong ?

```
<div radiolist></div>
```

JS

```
app.directive('radiolist', function() {
var templateHtml = function () {
    return '<label  ng-repeat="option in options" > <input type="radio" ng-disabled="{{isDisabled}}" name="{{attributename}}" ng-value="option.Value" ng-model="$parent.ngModel" />{{option.Desc}} </label>'; 
};
return {
    template: templateHtml,
    link : function(scope, element) {
        scope.options = [
          {
            "Value" : "Y",
            "Desc" : "Yes"
          },
          {
            "Value" : "N",
            "Desc" : "No"
          }
        ]

        console.log(angular.element(element).children())
       }

    };
});
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/SUFXunVLOhYfK1x4jVe2?p=preview

Comment: I won't be able to use $compile(template)(scope) as the code goes to infinite loop

Comment: Hey, was this problem solved by my answer? Please accept it if it was.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't see the children is because when the link function is called the directive has just finished compiling. There are no children because the ng-repeat hasn't had a chance to render anything yet.

I would recommend you restructure your code to not have to get access to the children, I assume because you want to add listeners to the radio buttons. Try explicitly defining each radiobutton instead of using ng-repeat.

Finally, the element is already an angular element, you don't need to wrap it again. Fix that line in your code to continue debugging.

Edit:

This mod of your plunkr might help you with the event bindings, I added ng-click to the rendered elements of ng-repeat, and passed the index of the radiobutton back:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fABRl8OGMywsilmo9m8e?p=preview

```
app.directive('radiolist', function() {
    var templateHtml = function () {
        return '<label  ng-repeat="option in options" >' +
         '<input ng-click="someFunction($index)" type="radio" ng-disabled="{{isDisabled}}" name="{{attributename}}" ' +
         'ng-value="option.Value" ng-model="$parent.ngModel" />{{option.Desc}} </label>'; 
    };
    return {
        template: templateHtml,
        link : function(scope, element) {
            scope.options = [
              {
                "Value" : "Y",
                "Desc" : "Yes"
              },
              {
                "Value" : "N",
                "Desc" : "No"
              }
            ]
            scope.someFunction = function(index) {
              console.log('clicked:', index);
            }
            // Don't fix this, but at least don't wrap element again
            console.log('children:', element.children()); 
        }

    };
});
```